# How to type arabic latters with (Tashkeel : vowelization) using java

Tags: java, android, unicode, fonts, arabic

I want to be able to type arabic letters with `harakat (Tashkeel)`. How to type that using Java ?

like this example:

```
اللُغَة الْعربِيّة بِالتّشْكِيل
```

You notice the signs above and below the letters ?

I will need it ti enable the use input text with (Tashkeel) in label , text field ..etc

For example:
I want to use it in android application, to enable output the Arabic letters with vowelization

Comment: please explain a bit more?

Comment: What do you mean by 'type arabic letters'? Do you mean in your source code or in a Java program with an Edit Text or something similar? The signs above the letters don't show for me in Notepad, but they do in UTF-8 Encoding in Altova XML Spy... could it be something simple like that?

Comment: Java supports unicode. Arabic characters are part of this standard. So, what is your specific problem and what kind of application are you working on (SWING, web, etc)

Comment: @AlexR I should have mentioned that, I was guessing it is the actual IDE he is using is the issue, rather than the Java output. It's not clear at all.

Comment: @RossC, OP've updated the question and now it is clearer: the question is about Android app.

Comment: Is it in your actual app that the text is incorrect? What type of object is displaying the text? What encoding is it set to? I still don't know what you're asking in this question! As AlexR said Java supports Unicode including these characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment java supports unicode, so it is not a problem to represent any string that contains any characters into java application. If you are developing Android application I guess that you want your user to use keyboard application to type his texts. These texts then will arrive to your application. If keyboard supports Arabic no problems are expected. If it does not support Arabic user will have to switch to other keyboard.

All this is relevant unless you are developing the new virtual keyboard. In this case, I guess you will have to support the logic that transforms letters during typing as all Arabic enabled typing systems do.